# Getting a prediction from a loaded tensor flow classification model, .pd file

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

Apologies if this is a trivial question. I just can't quite figure it out.
I followed the tutorial found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification. Built the model and trained it. I saved the model to disk with:
`<model_name>.save(<directory location>)`

This saved the following files in 'directory location':

A folder 'assets', this folder is empty. A folder 'variables' and 'saved_model.pb'

Using:

`loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('directory location', compile=True)`

I load the saved model. Then with

`loaded_model.summary()`

I get:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 150, 150, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 75, 75, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 75, 75, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 75, 75, 32)        4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 37, 37, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 37, 37, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 18, 18, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 18, 18, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 20736)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               10617344  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 10,641,441
Trainable params: 10,641,441
Non-trainable params: 0
```

This makes me think the model loaded correctly. Here I get stuck. How do I feed this model a single image and get a prediction, in this case cat or dog? I have searched the web and various answers here and I got as far as:

`prediction = loaded_model.predict(???)`

I do not know what the ??? needs to be. A concrete example of how to get a prediction for an image file would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification)  the input shape for the model is 150,150,3 so in order to make a prediction we need read the image and resize it to make a prediction. (Assuming your image is in RGB or BGR)

```
import cv2

preprocessed_image = cv2.imread("Path to Image")
preprocessed_image = cv2.resize(preprocessed_image,(150,150))
preprocessed_image = preprocessed_image.reshape(1,150,150,3)
prediction = loaded_model.predict(preprocessed_image)
```

Comment: The code suggested gives me the following error 'ValueError: error when checking input: expected con2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (150, 150, 3). Is the model maybe expecting an array of images instead of a single image?

Comment: yes i can see the model expects 4D array. but you can try with. " preprocessed_image = preprocessed_image.reshape(1,150,150,3) " I have made the edit in the main ans you try and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you that works. I also created an array of images in which case I do not have to reshape the individual images. I am getting an array of probabilities, now to figure out what they mean. I will need to figure out how to print the labels associated with the resulting probabilities. Feeding an array of 'dog' images into the model results in more or less the same probability list as an array of cat images,

Comment: What is the test accuracy of your model.

Comment: non augmented: acc = 96% valid. acc = 82% 10 epochs, so it overfits, augmented: acc = 75%, valid acc = 78%, evaluated with unseen images= 79%, prediction accuracy=76% 10 epochs. For augmented with 100 epochs acc = 86% and valid. acc = 86%. I think it's ok, I guess I expected better for the number of images. All is well.